# jupyterLab %%timeit not consistent with python timeit

Tags: python, type-hinting

I wanted to test if type hinting had an influence on how long did the code take to run. It probably would add a tiny bit of time because the compiler has to ignore it, and that takes time but I wanted to see how unsignificant this was.

To do this, I executed this on jupyterLab:
[image]

However, one of my classmates tried this without jupyterLab and found this:
[image]

Does someone have an explanation as to why this would be happening?

Functions used:

```
def func(a, b):
    return a + b
func(6, 7)
```

and:

```
def func(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
func(6, 7)
```

Comment: Please provide code as text, not images

Comment: Edited my post with the code.

Comment: Separate the function definition and execution in Jupyter, and time the execution only. Then compare those two timings.

Comment: The function definition is what takes more time in Jupyter.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kXWSiJN.png

Comment: What times do you get if you execute the definitions inside functions, i.e., [like this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNQ9OKSwEIwJzSvGSNRB2FJKgYCBSllpQW5SkkKmgrJHEBVf//DwA)?

Comment: @KellyBundy  https://i.imgur.com/fsKUWzS.png

Comment: So still a difference even though without jupyterlab there doesn't seem to be one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed yourself, *"The function definition is what takes more time"*.

#### Why you saw a difference

Pythengers, disassemble!

```
import dis

dis.dis('''
def func(a, b):
    return a + b
''')
```

Output (using Python 3.10.4):

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object func at 0x00000243938989D0, file "<dis>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('func')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (func)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object func at 0x00000243938989D0, file "<dis>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Loads the compiled code object, makes a function object from it, and assigns it to the name `func`.

With the annotated version, we instead get this:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('a')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('b')
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('return')
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              6
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object func at 0x00000243940F0A80, file "<dis>", line 2>)
             16 LOAD_CONST               4 ('func')
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            4 (annotations)
             20 STORE_NAME               1 (func)
             22 LOAD_CONST               5 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object func at 0x00000243940F0A80, file "<dis>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So when *that* gets executed, some additional stuff gets done for the annotations, which costs additional time.

#### Why your classmate didn't see a difference

Why does it not make a difference for your classmate's way of measuring? Because they're not really measuring it. Try printing something in `a.py`:

```
print('importing a.py ...')
def func(a, b):
    return a + b
func(6, 7)
```

Then try it again:

```
> python -m timeit -n 10000000 "import a"
importing a.py ...
10000000 loops, best of 5: 370 nsec per loop
>
```

Ten million loops, but our message only got printed *once*. Because Python caches imports and doesn't reimport what's already imported. So while this *does* measure a **single** execution of the function definition, that's utterly insignificant among executing ten million import statements. Really your classmate didn't measure the code they intended to measure, but measured *import statements* (almost all of which got recognized as reimports and then ignored).

Comment: Huh! Never heard of `dis` before. Interesting! Good catch on imports

Answer (score 0):

I think magic functions such as `%%timeit` cause the notebook to interpret the cell. Running your code in both a command line and a notebook, I get similar results to yours.

However, if I define the functions `afunc` and `bfunc` in one cell and then `%%timeit` each in a different cell, results are consistent with each other again.

```
[1]
def afunc(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

def bfunc(a, b):
    return a + b
```

```
[2]
%%timeit
afunc(1,2)
40.9 ns ± 0.131 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

```
[3]
%%timeit
bfunc(1,2)
42.9 ns ± 0.0417 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

No significant difference, whereas

```
[1]
%%timeit
def afunc(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
afunc(1,2)

145 ns ± 0.765 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

```
[2]
%%timeit
def bfunc(a, b):
    return a + b
bfunc(1,2)
71.2 ns ± 0.341 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Gives us a massive difference

We can take it further and do this:

```
[1]
%%timeit
def afunc(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
111 ns ± 0.358 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

```
[2]
%%timeit
def bfunc(a, b):
    return a + b
32.6 ns ± 0.255 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Here it becomes obvious that interpretation is what is being measured as no user function call is being executed, just the definition of the function itself. We observe the same discrepancy, minus the ~40ns to run either function.

Simpler code in a console seems to confirm that this isn't specific to JupyterLab, although this code is much simpler to fit `exec`'s requirements:

```
C:\Users\Ben>python -m timeit "exec('a: int = 1')"
50000 loops, best of 5: 4.91 usec per loop

C:\Users\Ben>python -m timeit "exec('a = 1')"
50000 loops, best of 5: 4.02 usec per loop
```

Comment: Yes, but without jupyterLab, surely this interpretation time should come into play as well, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `timeit` interprets your code once and executes it 10 million time.  If you define your function and execute it in a block using `%%timeit`, you also interpret the function 10 million times.

You can prove this by defining your function in a cell and executing it in a different cell with `%%timeit`. Your two results will then be similar. `%%timeit` is the equivalent of running exec('def f(a: int, b: int): ...)'

Comment: I've edited my answer to give concrete demonstrations

Comment: *"no actual code is being executed."* - Not true. The function definition is executed. And your `exec` thing is *not* equivalent, as that additionally includes parsing/compiling.

Comment: Edited my answer for accuracy. I meant no user function call is being executed. There's also code being executed to display text in the browser! :D

As far as I know though, the notebook does parse and compile code, which is the very reason we see a difference in performance from one block to the other.

Comment: I hightly doubt the notebook includes the parsing/compiling in the timing. That's not what people are interested in when they benchmark. See my answer now for a difference in what happens when the function definitions get executed (after already having been parsed/compiled).